# Is there a way to log SQL queries in IBM Data Studio?

Tags: db2, reverse-engineering, ibm-midrange

Is there a way to retrieve the SQL queries sent to an IBM db 2 database from the IBM data Studio ?

I need to reverse engineer an IBM db 2 database that is tied to an AS400 application but unfortunately there is almost no documentation and a lot of schemas/tables are quite obscure.

I have tried to sniff the network from the client side as I heard it communicates in cleartext to the server (via telnet) but unfortunately the SQL is not generated client side.

As I am running out of solution I am exploring IBM Data Studio as a last chance. Does anyone know if it is possible ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very confusing...and seems to demonstrate a lack of basic knowledge about the IBM i platform and it's predecessor the AS/400.

You mention Telnet, so I assume the existing application is a green screen 5250 application.  Yeah, that's just a "dumb" terminal emulation.  There's no SQL being used from the 5250 client.

Assuming the application uses SQL at all, it would be server side and embedded in the DB or the RPG/COBOL programs being run.  It's probably mostly native record level access (RLA) reads and writes.

It's also possible that the tables being used are not externally defined.  Meaning the as far as the DB knows, the tables are made up of a single fixed length character field.  You'd have to inspect the RPG/COBOL programs to determine how the data is actually stored in the records.  I wouldn't expect this even for an AS/400 application, as the original AS/400 supported externally described files (tables).  But if your application was migrated from one of the AS/400's predecessors...then it's more likely.

Assuming the tables are externally defined, a `SELECT * FROM MYLIB.MYTABLE`  will return the data in individual columns.  I don't think IBM Data Studio will do much more than point you to the [catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-db2-i-catalog-views) which are quite well documented.

Assuming you're not actually dealing with an AS/400 and instead have a somewhat modern application that uses SQL, running on a modern POWER server running a recent version of IBM i.  Then the answer to your question about capturing the SQL queries being is that the server has [lots of tools built in](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=optimization-tools) to manage SQL performance.  Including an automated plan cache that you can view to see recent queries using IBM's [Access Client Solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions)

But to re-iterate, I wouldn't expect a 5250 application to be entirely or even mostly SQL based.

If all you're trying to do is reverse engineer the DB, that should be mostly do-able if the tables are externally defined.  Though you might find out the tables / indexes don't have unique (primary) keys defined.

If you're trying to reverse engineer the entire application, that will be very difficult without access to the RPG/COBOL source.

Comment: To add a little information, in a TN5250 environment, all of the database queries are done by the server; the communication between the server and the telnet device are strictly for reading and writing to the display. The TN5250 client does not execute any program logic, no business rules, no SQL queries. All of that is done by the programs running on the IBM i server. Which is why you need to have access to the source code for those programs to reverse engineer an IBM i application.